# Skip captcha resolution step while using Google IMAP server

Tags: gmail, imap, captcha, gmail-imap

I am developing a product which analyze Gmail account data and for that I need to allow user to log in to their Gmail account from my product. Now everything is going perfect no problem is there in execution. But when a new user come each time he/ she has to resolve Google Captch page (https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha). Now this is being hesitation to users and I want to skip this step. So is there any way through which I can eliminate this step?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Anvesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I came to know that I can my domain to Google account which will allow me to register my web application. Anyone can register through this link `https://accounts.google.com/ManageDomains`

It's just simple many documents available for guidance.

Thanks,
Anvesh